# crash on grabbing item from array... objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

Lost...

keeps crashing when I try to get an item from the array (tourresult) after I press on a cell. I'd like to grab the index from the array so I can create an object and pass that on to the next window. Looks like my array is being released somewhere, but I've not set autorelease on it, nor am i releasing it anywhere. I've turned on Zombie and other things, but it's not giving me anything else but "message sent to deallocated instance" but it's not deallocated...

(ps: is this the right way to transfer data to another view?)

I've got the .h file setup with
NSMutableArray *tourResult;
and property and syntesize in the .m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSDictionary* loan = [tourResult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    Tour *tour = [[[Tour alloc] init] autorelease];
    tour.tourID = [loan objectForKey:@"partner_id"];
    tour.tourName = [loan objectForKey:@"name"];
    tour.tourDescription = [loan objectForKey:@"use"];
    tour.tourLat = [[loan objectForKey:@"loan_amount"] floatValue];
    tour.tourLon = [[loan objectForKey:@"id"] floatValue];


    TableViewDetailViewController *fvController = [[TableViewDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TableViewDetailViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    fvController.tour = tour;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:fvController animated:YES];
    [fvController release];
    fvController = nil;

}

- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData 
{

    //parse out the json data
    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    tourResult = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    tourResult = [json objectForKey:@"loans"];
    for (int x = 0;x < [tourResult count];x++)
    {
        NSDictionary* loan = [tourResult objectAtIndex:x];
        [itemsList addObject:[loan objectForKey:@"name"]];
    }
    [itemsList removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    [myTableView reloadData];

}

-(void)loadView
{

    myTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame] style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    myTableView.delegate = self;
    myTableView.dataSource = self;

    myTableView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;

    itemsList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [itemsList addObject:@"Loading..."];

    self.navigationItem.title = @"Tours";
    self.view = myTableView;

    dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: kLatestKivaLoansURL];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning tourResult ***twice*** in your "`fetchedData:`" method.  The first one allocates it.  The second assignment is an "`objectForKey:`" from your json object (and "`objectForKey:`" may or may not return nil).

So you're losing (and leaking) the first created object and possibly not getting anything valid in your second assignment.

Comment: i've got it. it was the second line. The "ObjectForKey" is an autorelease object. I had to "retain" it manually. thanks!!!

Comment: If you want to create a mutable array from your json object, do it via "`tourResult = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: arrayFromJSON];`" (where `arrayFromJSON` is a valid, non-nil array that you retrieved via "`objectForKey`").

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can try this in your method `fetchedData:`:

```
   tourResult = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   [tourResult addObjectsFromArray:[json objectForKey:@"loans"]];
```